# Convert JS Array to a nested Object

Tags: javascript

What is the best way to convert:

```
['[Title A]','child A','child B', '[Title B]', 'child C', 'child D']
```

to:

```
{
  0: {
      'title': 'Title A',
      'children': ['child A', 'child B']
     }
  1: {
       'title': 'Title B',
       'children': ['Child C', 'Child D']
     }
}
```

I have this so far which checks on the presence of brackets [] and I tried to add this to an object with a dynamic index which increments during a for loop every time a title with brackets is found:

```
let index = 0;
let listObject = {};
for (const listItem of listItems) {
   const titleValue = listItem.match(/\[(.*?)\]/);
   if (titleValue) {
     ++index;
     listObject[index].title = titleValue[1];
   } else {
     listObject[index].children = [listItem];
   }
}

console.log(listObject);
```

Comment: Why is the result an object with "numierc" properties with objects and not an array of objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const array = ['[Title A]','child A','child B', '[Title B]', 'child C', 'child D'];

let objToPush = {};
let objToSend = {};
array.map((d) => {
 if (/^\[[^\]]+\]$/.test(d)) {
  if (Object.keys(objToPush).length > 0) {
     objToSend[Object.keys(objToSend).length] = { ...objToPush };
     objToPush = {};
  }
  objToPush.title = d.substring(1, d.length - 1);
 } else {
  objToPush.children = objToPush.children ? [...objToPush.children, d] : [d]
 }
});
objToSend[Object.keys(objToSend).length] = { ...objToPush };
console.log('objToPush', objToSend);
```

it worked for me (JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/wepbzdfL/48/)

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of **simplicity** let's first make an array of objects:

```
const res = arr.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  const titleValue = cur.match(/\[(.*?)\]/)
  titleValue ?
    acc.push({
      title: cur,
      children: []
    }) :
    acc[acc.length - 1].children.push(cur)

  return acc
}, [])
```

Now you can use the `spread operator` to have the **nested object**:

```
{...res}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just updated yours so the logic is sound. Can see what you tried.

Read up on creating new objects and arrays in JS, and when you can add to them.

```js
let listItems = ['[Title A]', 'child A', 'child B', '[Title B]', 'child C', 'child D'];

let index = 0;
var listObject = {};
for (const listItem of listItems) {
  const isTitle = listItem[0] == "[" && listItem[listItem.length - 1] == "]"
  if (isTitle) {
    ++index;
    listObject[index] = {
      title: listItem.substring(1, listItem.length -1),
      children: [] //Create Array
    }; //Create Object
  } else {
    listObject[index].children.push(listItem); //Add to children array
  }
}

console.log(listObject);
```

To add on why I used an index lookup, instead of regex,

Run this:

```js
var testArray = [];

var arrayCount = 20000000;

var regexMatch = /\[(.*?)\]/;

for (var i = 0; i < arrayCount; i++) {
  testArray.push("[" + makeid(Math.round(Math.random() * 10)) + "]")
}

console.log(testArray.length);
var start = new Date();
console.log(start.toString());

for (var i = 0; i < arrayCount; i++) {
  var testItem = testArray[i];
  if (testItem.match(regexMatch)) {

  } else {

  }
}

console.log("regex took " + (new Date().getTime() - start.getTime()) / 1000 + " seconds");

start = new Date();
for (var i = 0; i < arrayCount; i++) {
  var testItem = testArray[i];
  if (testItem[0] === "[" && testItem[testItem.length - 1] === "]") {

  } else {

  }
}

console.log("index lookup took " + (new Date().getTime() - start.getTime()) / 1000 + " seconds");

function makeid(length) {
  var result = '';
  var characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
  var charactersLength = characters.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
  }
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the "best" way, but this is my solution:

```js
const array = [
  "[Title A]",
  "child A",
  "child B",
  "[Title B]",
  "child C",
  "child D"
];

let index = -1;
const res = array.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  if (/^\[[^\]]+\]$/.test(curr)) {
    acc = {
      ...acc,
      [++index]: { title: curr.substring(1, curr.length - 1), children: [] }
    };
  } else {
    acc[index].children = [...acc[index].children, curr];
  }
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(res);
```